# Installing optipng with homebrew: command not found (rbenv?)

Tags: macos, terminal, rubygems, homebrew, rbenv

I've successfully installed optipng:

```
  $ brew install optipng
  ==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/optipng/OptiPNG/optipng-0.7.5/optipng-0.7.5.tar.gz
  Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/optipng-0.7.5.tar.gz
  ==> Patching
  patching file src/optipng/osys.c
  ==> ./configure --with-system-zlib --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/optipng/0.7.5 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/optipng/0.7.5/share/man
  ==> make install
    /usr/local/Cellar/optipng/0.7.5: 6 files, 156K, built in 2 seconds
```

but when I use the command it says the following:

```
$ optipng
rbenv: optipng: command not found

The `optipng' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  jruby-1.7.10
  jruby-1.7.11
  jruby-1.7.9
```

If I use this path `/usr/local/Cellar/optipng/0.7.5/bin/optipng` it works!!

Has this something to do with rbenv? Or why isn't the optipng command global?

```
$ rbenv global
1.9.3-p429
```

I've also tried `brew unlink optipng` and `brew link optipng` -> same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found out that I had the `image_optim_bin` gem in one of my projects installed, after uninstalling this gem for all ruby versions, the command finally works!

```
$ gem uninstall image_optim_bin
Remove executables:
  advdef, advmng, advpng, advzip, jpegoptim, jpegtran, optipng, pngcrush, pngout

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  
Removing advdef
Removing advmng
Removing advpng
Removing advzip
Removing jpegoptim
Removing jpegtran
Removing optipng
Removing pngcrush
Removing pngout
Successfully uninstalled image_optim_bin-0.0.4
```

opened new terminal and now it works:

```
$ optipng
Synopsis:
    optipng [options] files ...
Files:
    Image files of type: PNG, BMP, GIF, PNM or TIFF
Basic options:
    -?, -h, -help show the extended help
    -o <level>    optimization level (0-7)    [default: 2]
    -v      run in verbose mode / show copyright and version info
```